# addClass not adding validation classes but working with other classes

Tags: jquery, validation, addclass

I am using jQuery to add a new form entry into my form, and need to add some classes to validate the input for the fields. When I save and load the page in Firefox or Chrome the validation classes are not added ("validate-select", "required-entry", "validate-zip", etc.) The other classes are adding just fine. I set up a fiddle for it and it is not working there either, so it is not a javascript conflict. I've also run it through JSHint with no errors:

```
function addSection(position){
    var newli = document.createElement('li');
    newli.setAttribute("class", "field content "+position);
    var country = jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("id", "dest_country_id"+position).attr("name", "dest_country_id"+position).addClass("dest_country_id").attr("value", "US"); 
    var statecontents = "<option value=''>Select a state</option>"+"";
    var state = jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("picker state").append(jQuery("<select></select>").attr("id", "dest_region_id"+position).addClass("validate-select input select dest_region_id").append(statecontents));
    var zip = jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("zip").append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "dest_zip"+position).attr("name", "dest_zip"+position).addClass("dest_zip required-entry input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "starting zip")).append(jQuery("<span></span>").text(" to ")).append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "dest_zip_to"+position).attr("name", "dest_zip_to"+position).addClass("dest_zip_to required-entry input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "ending zip"));
    var weight = jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("weight").append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "weight_from"+position).attr("name", "weight_from"+position).addClass("required-entry weight_from input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "starting weight")).append(jQuery("<span></span>").text(" - ")).append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "weight_to"+position).attr("name", "weight_to"+position).addClass("weight_to required-entry input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "ending weight"));
    var price = jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("price").append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "price"+position).attr("name", "price"+position).addClass("price required-entry input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "price"));
    var remove = jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("delete").append(jQuery("<a></a>").attr("href", "#").attr("onclick", "removeRule("+position+"); return false;").append(jQuery("<i></i>").addClass("icon-trash mp_delete")));
    var stateHead = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("class","state-wrap").append(jQuery("<span></span>").attr("class","form-head").text(" State ")).append(jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("picker state").append(jQuery("<select></select>").attr("id", "dest_region_id"+position).attr("name", "dest_region_id"+position).addClass("input select dest_region_id").append(statecontents)));
    var zipHead = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("class","zip-wrap").append(jQuery("<span></span>").attr("class","form-head").text(" ZIP Code Range ")).append(jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("zip").append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "dest_zip"+position).attr("name", "dest_zip"+position).addClass("dest_zip input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "Starting ZIP")).append(jQuery("<span></span>").text(" to ")).append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "dest_zip_to"+position).attr("name", "dest_zip_to"+position).addClass("dest_zip_to input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "Ending ZIP")));
    var weightHead = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("class","weight-wrap").append(jQuery("<span></span>").attr("class","form-head").text(" Weight ")).append(jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("weight").append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "weight_from"+position).attr("name", "weight_from"+position).addClass("weight_from input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "Starting Weight")).append(jQuery("<span></span>").text(" to ")).append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "weight_to"+position).attr("name", "weight_to"+position).addClass("weight_to input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "Ending Weight")));
    var priceHead = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("class","price-wrap").append(jQuery("<span></span>").attr("class","form-head").text(" Price ")).append(jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("price").append(jQuery("<input></input>").attr("type", "text").attr("id", "price"+position).attr("name", "price"+position).addClass("price input text xnarrow").attr("placeholder", "Price")));
    var removeHead = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("class","remove-wrap").append(jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("delete btn metro").append(jQuery("<a></a>").attr("href", "#").attr("onclick", "removeRule("+position+"); return false;").text("Cancel").append(jQuery("<i></i>").addClass("icon-trash mp_delete"))));
    var addHead = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("class","add-wrap").append(jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("medium metro btn default").append(jQuery("<a></a>").addClass("add_btn").attr("href","#").text("Add a rate").append(jQuery("<i></i>").addClass("icon-plus-squared"))));
    var title = jQuery("<div></div>").attr("class","rate-title").append(jQuery("<span></span>").text("Add a New Rate:"));
    var ni = document.getElementById('add-rates');
    jQuery(newli).append(title,country,stateHead,zipHead,weightHead,priceHead,removeHead,addHead);
    ni.appendChild(newli);
    position++;
    return position;
}


<li class="field content 0"><div class="rate-title"><span>Add a New Rate:</span></div><input type="hidden" id="dest_country_id0" name="dest_country_id0" class="dest_country_id" value="US"><div class="state-wrap"><span class="form-head"> State </span><div class="picker state"><select id="dest_region_id0" name="dest_region_id0" class="input select dest_region_id"><option value="">Select a state</option><option value="1">Alabama</option><option value="2">Alaska</option><option value="3">American Samoa</option><option value="4">Arizona</option><option value="5">Arkansas</option><option value="6">Armed Forces Africa</option><option value="7">Armed Forces Americas</option><option value="8">Armed Forces Canada</option><option value="9">Armed Forces Europe</option><option value="10">Armed Forces Middle East</option><option value="11">Armed Forces Pacific</option><option value="12">California</option><option value="13">Colorado</option><option value="14">Connecticut</option><option value="15">Delaware</option><option value="16">District of Columbia</option><option value="17">Federated States Of Micronesia</option><option value="18">Florida</option><option value="19">Georgia</option><option value="20">Guam</option><option value="21">Hawaii</option><option value="22">Idaho</option><option value="23">Illinois</option><option value="24">Indiana</option><option value="25">Iowa</option><option value="26">Kansas</option><option value="27">Kentucky</option><option value="28">Louisiana</option><option value="29">Maine</option><option value="30">Marshall Islands</option><option value="31">Maryland</option><option value="32">Massachusetts</option><option value="33">Michigan</option><option value="34">Minnesota</option><option value="35">Mississippi</option><option value="36">Missouri</option><option value="37">Montana</option><option value="38">Nebraska</option><option value="39">Nevada</option><option value="40">New Hampshire</option><option value="41">New Jersey</option><option value="42">New Mexico</option><option value="43">New York</option><option value="44">North Carolina</option><option value="45">North Dakota</option><option value="46">Northern Mariana Islands</option><option value="47">Ohio</option><option value="48">Oklahoma</option><option value="49">Oregon</option><option value="50">Palau</option><option value="51">Pennsylvania</option><option value="52">Puerto Rico</option><option value="53">Rhode Island</option><option value="54">South Carolina</option><option value="55">South Dakota</option><option value="56">Tennessee</option><option value="57">Texas</option><option value="58">Utah</option><option value="59">Vermont</option><option value="60">Virgin Islands</option><option value="61">Virginia</option><option value="62">Washington</option><option value="63">West Virginia</option><option value="64">Wisconsin</option><option value="65">Wyoming</option></select></div></div><div class="zip-wrap"><span class="form-head"> ZIP Code Range </span><div class="zip"><input type="text" id="dest_zip0" name="dest_zip0" class="dest_zip input text xnarrow" placeholder="Starting ZIP"><span> to </span><input type="text" id="dest_zip_to0" name="dest_zip_to0" class="dest_zip_to input text xnarrow" placeholder="Ending ZIP"></div></div><div class="weight-wrap"><span class="form-head"> Weight </span><div class="weight"><input type="text" id="weight_from0" name="weight_from0" class="weight_from input text xnarrow" placeholder="Starting Weight"><span> to </span><input type="text" id="weight_to0" name="weight_to0" class="weight_to input text xnarrow" placeholder="Ending Weight"></div></div><div class="price-wrap"><span class="form-head"> Price </span><div class="price"><input type="text" id="price0" name="price0" class="price input text xnarrow" placeholder="Price"></div></div><div class="remove-wrap"><div class="delete btn metro"><a href="#" onclick="removeRule(0); return false;">Cancel<i class="icon-trash mp_delete"></i></a></div></div><div class="add-wrap"><div class="medium metro btn default"><a class="add_btn" href="#">Add a rate<i class="icon-plus-squared"></i></a></div></div></li>
```

Similar code is working in other locations on my site, and the classes show up when I inspect the elements in Firefox and Chrome. Am I adding the classes to the wrong element?

Comment: such a messy code, what exactly the problem is?

Comment: I've added an example of the HTML it is producing. The validate-select and required-entry classes dissappear.

Comment: There it is - my partner must have added all of the new elements he added to the jQuery(newli).append line and removed the ones that had the validation rules. My bad. Thanks for trying to help.